# MATLAB streamribbon edge color

Tags: matlab

In a streamribbon plot, how do you plot the edges of the ribbon itself, as opposed to the edges of every face?

**For example:**

```
figure
load wind
[sx sy sz] = meshgrid(80,20:10:50,0:5:15);
h = streamribbon(x,y,z,u,v,w,sx,sy,sz);
axis tight
shading interp;
view(3);
camlight
lighting gouraud
```

Produces:
[image: Raw output]

If I add `set(h,'edgecolor','k')`

I get:
[image: Output with edge turned to 'k']

Whereas what I'm looking for is something like this (top and left sides of image have been edited with gimp, to make the point of what I'm chasing):
[image: Edited with gimp]

Comment: Do you want JUST the edges or the eddges and the faces (as in your last image)? PD: Borderlands.

Comment: I dont think there is an easy way to this. The handles returned by `streamribbon` are surface handles per ribbon. There, knowing if an edge is in the boundary and plotting that (but not the ones inside) is definitely not straightforward. I guess you could writte a code that takes a surface and tells you which points are on the edges of that surface, and then you could just plot 3D lines there. Computationally not cheap but very nice ressults I guess.

Comment: @AnderBiguri. It works. Quite nice result indeed. And computationally it's not the worst since we only need to re-use/reorder existing data (nothing new computed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment, there is no easy way to illuminate some edges of the ribbon surfaces and not other.

However, the ribbon surfaces are simply defined by the points on the edges, so it is only a matter of retrieving these points and reorganizing them (inline them) to get a perfect coordinate set for 3D lines.
To get a *closed* profile, we just need to replicate the first point at the end of the profile.

I packaged that into a function which will return a set of `handles` the same size as the ribbon handle array, and transfer any additional parameters you can send to the internal `plot3` function. So the usage is quite straightforward:

So using exactly the same code than in the question (which retrieve the array of ribbon surface handle in the variable `h`), adding:

```
hs = StreamEdges( h , 'k','Linewidth',1 ) ;
```

will produce:
[image: streamborder]

Of course, you can always get crazy and set your line properties in group:

```
set(hs,'LineWidth',1,'Color','c')
%// or
set(hs,'LineWidth',2,'Color','r','Marker','none')
```

[image: other edges]

---

**Code for function `StreamEdges.m` :**

```
function hs = StreamEdges(hribbon,varargin)

wasOnHold = ishold ;            %// save hold state
hold on

hs = zeros( size(hribbon) ) ;   %// initialize output handle array
for ih=1:numel( hribbon ) ;
    %// retrieve X, Y, and Z data of each surface
    hsurf = handle( hribbon(ih)) ;  %// for pre-HG2 (2014a) versions
    xx = hsurf.XData ;
    yy = hsurf.YData ;
    zz = hsurf.ZData ;

    %// reoder coordinates to linearise surface profile (edge)
    xx = [xx(:,1) ; flipud(xx(:,2)) ; xx(1)] ;
    yy = [yy(:,1) ; flipud(yy(:,2)) ; yy(1)] ;
    zz = [zz(:,1) ; flipud(zz(:,2)) ; zz(1)] ;

    %// return double to stay compatible with pre-HG2
    hs(ih) = double( plot3(xx(:),yy(:),zz(:), varargin{:} ) ) ;
end

if ~wasOnHold ; hold off ; end      %// restore hold state
hs = handle(hs) ;                   %// convert "double" handle back to HG2 handles
```

---

The function should work with version pre-HG2 (=pre 2014b) or post-HG2. The handle array it will return will be in the HG2 format (= real handle, not just their `double` representation). This gives you access to the dot notation on your graphic object even for version pre-HG2. If you are not comfortable with that, just comment the last line of the function (*or to get the old handle style you can always use the function* `hs = double(hs)`)

---

**Target `axes`**

Apart from the preservation of the `hold` state, the function will behave like most high level plot function, meaning they will go directly to the current `axes` (`gca`), or create a new one if none exist.
You can easily modify the function to accept an `axes` handle as target, or simply without modification, call it explicitly in the parameters:

```
hs = StreamEdges( h , 'Parent','target_axes_handle' , 'Color','k','Linewidth',1) ;
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! I did have to change the 'xData' to 'XData' - running R2014b, to get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @James, Thanks it's corrected now (also with slight modifications of the function).

Comment: Brilliant! This gives a very nice effect in the plots!